# Carregar form_dropdown no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

No `controller` tenho este ***método***:

```
<?php 
class Projetos extends CI_Controller {
public function index() 
{
    $data['dados_clientes'] = $this->clientes_model->get_clientes();

    $data['main_view'] = 'projetos/index';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
}
```

Como colocar o que está em `dados_clientes` no `dropdown`?

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Cliente'); ?>
        <?php 
            $data = array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'name' => 'proj_cliente',
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_dropdown($data);?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como é dito na **documentação** do próprio [Framework CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/) o [form_dropdown](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_dropdown#form_dropdown), preciso de um [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) do estilo: ***chave*** e ***valor*** (*key and value*).

***Exemplo:***

```
$array = []; // ou $array = array();
$array['1'] => 'Item 1';
$array['2'] => 'Item 2';
$array['3'] => 'Item 3';
```

Porque a chave (key) é o value do [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), e valor (*value*) é o texto do [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

Então o seu model terá que retornar um array com esse estilo para que funcione o carregamento das informações.

---

***Demonstração da própria documentação:***

```
$options = array(
        'small'         => 'Small Shirt',
        'med'           => 'Medium Shirt',
        'large'         => 'Large Shirt',
        'xlarge'        => 'Extra Large Shirt',
);

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

***Resultado:***

```
<select name="shirts">
     <option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
     <option value="med">Medium  Shirt</option>
     <option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
     <option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

***Sendo que:***

[form_dropdown](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_dropdown#form_dropdown) possui 4 *(quatro)* paramentos:

1. O primeiro é o nome do seu [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).
2. O segundo é o [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) de informações no formato logo acima explicado
3. O terceiro é qual dos itens do [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) é para ficar em evidencia, ou seja, selecionado (*selected="selected"*)
4. O quarto é [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) de configurações extras no mesmo estilo do [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) de informações

---

**Simulação de exemplo:**

***Tabela exemplo:***

```
creditos
    id
    nome
```

***Model:***

*Crie um método no seu model que representa esse código:*

```
public function lists()
{   
    $this->db->select('id,nome');
    $results = $this->db->get('creditos')->result();
    $list = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) 
    {
        $list[$result->id] = $result->nome;                
    }
    return $list;
}
```

***Carregue esse model em seu controller:***

```
public function index() 
{
    $data['dados_creditos'] = $this->credito_model->lists();
    $data['main_view'] = 'projetos/index';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
}
```

***Na sua view faça:***

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Creditos'); ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown($dados_creditos);?>
</div>
```

Exemplo, bem simples de carregamento das informações contidas em um base de dados, para a sua *View*.